# Superset Internal server error from Ambari

Tags: hadoop, ambari, druid

I am using Apache Ambari version 2.7.3. I was trying to install Superset from Ambari. But I am facing Issues While starting Superset. Below are the superset logs.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/hdp/3.1.4.0-315/superset/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1632, in finalize_request
    response = self.process_response(response)
  File "/usr/hdp/3.1.4.0-315/superset/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1858, in process_response
    self.save_session(ctx.session, response)
  File "/usr/hdp/3.1.4.0-315/superset/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 924, in save_session
    return self.session_interface.save_session(self, session, response)
  File "/usr/hdp/3.1.4.0-315/superset/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/sessions.py", line 363, in save_session
    val = self.get_signing_serializer(app).dumps(dict(session))
  File "/usr/hdp/3.1.4.0-315/superset/lib/python3.6/site-packages/itsdangerous/serializer.py", line 167, in dumps
    rv = self.make_signer(salt).sign(payload)
  File "/usr/hdp/3.1.4.0-315/superset/lib/python3.6/site-packages/itsdangerous/timed.py", line 42, in sign
    return value + sep + self.get_signature(value)
  File "/usr/hdp/3.1.4.0-315/superset/lib/python3.6/site-packages/itsdangerous/signer.py", line 143, in get_signature
    key = self.derive_key()
  File "/usr/hdp/3.1.4.0-315/superset/lib/python3.6/site-packages/itsdangerous/signer.py", line 132, in derive_key
    mac = hmac.new(self.secret_key, digestmod=self.digest_method)
  File "/usr/hdp/3.1.4.0-315/superset/lib/python3.6/hmac.py", line 144, in new
    return HMAC(key, msg, digestmod)
  File "/usr/hdp/3.1.4.0-315/superset/lib/python3.6/hmac.py", line 42, in __init__
    raise TypeError("key: expected bytes or bytearray, but got %r" % type(key).__name__)
TypeError: key: expected bytes or bytearray, but got 'int'
```

Answer (score 0):

After I changed the SECRET_KEY of Superset Database, then restarted server, it works. (Cannot work with pure numbers）